# Create pdf in a windows service out of SSRS output without using a web service

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

I have a windows service that creates an hourly PDF report out of some DB queries.

Currently, I'm doing it using the `reportViewer` control (`Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer`) and from it I render my report to PDF.
This method works, but I think there must be a simpler way to do that (since it's a windows service i'm not actually using the reportviewer for viewing purposes - and it seems kinda strange that there's nothing that will provide this functionality without the GUI part).

The question is: how to create a PDF by using the SSRS functionality without creating the GUI control or accessing a web service.

Thanks in advance,

Shmouel

Answer (score 0):

You can try IText component to create pdf.

Comment: A. How can I use the Itext with the SSRS reports? I don't see any way to link those two.
B. I would like more 'MS' way, since i need to use the ms reports anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I used telerik Report controls to do this. But i guess its the same if you use VS 2010 reports as well.

1. create a separate reports project in your solution and drag and drop ( or through code) create what ever report you want to generate.
2. expose a generate PDF method (public member) where you convert report to PDF
3. use this dll/project in your windows service solution
4. use the exposed method to create PDF for you.

I have done exactly this for our windows service.

Comment: The question is how to export the report to PDF without using the control (which is mainly for GUI purposes and i used it only as workaround)

Comment: Ok my bad. But what I meant was the dll created to be used is not a GUI control. Only when u load it up in report viewer youngest to see the GUI. The dll itself does not have any GUI classes in it